# how to convert series of integers into ordinals in C#

Tags: c#

i am having a texbox1 with series of integers i would like to know if their is any way i can apply the conversion of these integers into ordinals. below is what i have tried:
[image: textbox1 picture]

when my button convert is clicked with code:

```cs
    private void btnconvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (int num in txtresults.ToString())
            {
                string[] parts = txtresults.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                double[] numbers = parts.Select(p => double.Parse(p)).ToArray();
                double maximum = numbers.Max();
                int position = Array.IndexOf(numbers, maximum);
                parts[position] = **Ordinal(num);**
                txtresults.Text = string.Join(" ", parts);
            }
        }
```

this is my method of conversion

```cs
     public static string **Ordinal(int num)**
        {
            if (num <= 0) return num.ToString();

            switch (num % 100)
            {
                case 11:
                case 12:
                case 13:
                    return num + "th";
            }

            switch (num % 10)
            {
                case 1:
                    return num + "st";
                case 2:
                    return num + "nd";
                case 3:
                    return num + "rd";
                default:
                    return num + "th";
            }
        }
```

can i be thought how to do it right please (thanks in advance) (am using c# in wpf)

Comment: What is not working about the code?

Comment: everything i am guessing

Comment: This seems kind of suspect: `foreach (int num in txtresults.ToString())`

Comment: 1: Running foreach over a string will run it over each `char`, not each number. 2: You can't implicitly cast a `char` to an `int`.

Comment: Split your input string (split defaults to splitting on space btw), and for each substring, parse it to an integer (your input does not consist of decimal numbers and it does not make sense to apply ordinals to them), convert it to its ordinal representation, then join them back up again.

Comment: please greenjaed am sorry if i had offended you with my communication yesterday but please your code was useful can i get it back again please